# Is there a way to detect if a pen is in proximity to the screen in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft.ink

I want to be able to detect if I have a pen close to the screen or not.
I would like for example to show a different appbar if I open it with a pen.
Also I would like to show other things on the screen when I hold a pen close to it (not necessarily touching it).

/Jimmy

Comment: (Sounds cool, but .. can the hardware even detect that?)

Comment: Yep, pens ar detected a cm from the screen or so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a pen or finger is near the screen, you will get a [`PointerEntered`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.pointerentered.aspx) event. The [`PointerPressed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.icorewindow.pointerpressed.aspx) event fires when the pen or finger makes contact. If the hardware does not support proximity, then the `PointerEntered` does not fire until contact is made, and it will be followed immediately by a `PointerPressed`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
I listen to the PointerEntered-event and PointerExited-event and then sets a variable that I can check in the appbar_opened-event.
Works great.

/Jimmy